# Pass an object from ActionFilter.OnActionExecuting() to an ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I wish to create an object per http request within an ActionFilter and pass this object to the controller. So far I have tried Request.Properties[] like the following

```
public class DbReadonlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties["CustomObjectKey"] = new MyClass();
```

And I have also tried to assign the new object direct to a ControllerBase class.

```
public class DbReadonlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var controller = (MyControllerBase) actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
        controller.StorageContextFactory = new MyClass();
```

The problem is that neither technique delivers an instance of MyClass to the controller because the new Property["CustomObjectKey"] is lost in the Webapi pipeline by the time a controller method is invoked.

The controller is re-instantiated by the webapi pipeline after the call to action filter OnActionExecuting().

Break points confirm the Webapi pipeline schedules the following event flow during a single http request.

- constructor MyControllerBase()
- MyAuthenticationFilter
- Filter OnActionExecuting()
- constructor MyControllerBase()
- MyController.MethodA()

The double instantiation of MyControler is odd, but right now I am looking for any technique to pass a newly created object from an action filter to a controller.

Edit-1: The MyAuthorizationFilter mentioned in v1 of this question is actually an Authentication filter. Still investigating.

Solution: The bug was in another filter. After I removed my authentication filter the problem reported in this question went away.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will have to use `.add` method `Request.Properties` collection.

```
public class DbReadonlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("CustomObjectKey", new MyClass()));
```

You can retrieve this value from your api controller.

```
object _customObject= null;

if (Request.Properties.TryGetValue("CustomObjectKey", out _customObjectKey))
{
    MyClass myObject = (MyClass)_customObject;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am still getting the problem after applying your code change and I now suspect I have a deeper problem with the async chaining in my authentication filter.

Comment: I have been using the code I've pasted in my answer. It works fine for me.

Comment: I have simplified the problem by removing my global authentication filter declared in WebApiConfig as config.Filters.Add(x); The object passing from my action filter to the controller using your example and my original Properties["CustomObjectKey"] = technique is working for both examples. I am now investigating why my authentication filter is causing problems e.g. the double controller instantiation. If I fix this I will come back and credit your answer since your suggestion caused me to look for a deeper problem.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer because having confirmation it is possible to pass an object reference from an action filter to a controller via request properties forced me to review the whole filter chain which led to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to pass variable from ActionFilter.OnActionExecuting() to an ApiController:

```cs
public class CustomFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["CustomValue"] = "CustomValue";
    }
}
```

Pay attention to use ActionFilterAttribute for **Web API :**

> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute

**Not** for **MVC classic :**

> <s>System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute</s>

Using:

```cs
[CustomFilter]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    string customValue = RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value)["user_id"].ToString();
    //...
}
```